# tiling background image stops at bottom of content, not page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a background image to tile and cover the entire page, even if there isn't enough content to fill the page. Right now, the background image stops at the bottom of the content. I have used a sticky footer fix to keep the footer at bottom of the page, so what I'm left with is a bunch of white space between the bottom of the content and the footer.

I don't want to fill the space with `margin` or `padding`because that won't scale to larger monitors.

I've attached a picture of the problem:

[image]

Here is the CSS:

```
.static_pages {
    background-image: url('../img/cream_dust.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:  100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;

}

.static_content {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 3em auto 0 auto;
}
.static_content h1 {
    color: #193441;
}
.static_content p {
    color: #193441;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
.static_content ul {
    color: #193441;
}
```

And the HTML

```
<?php include_once('header.php'); ?>
    <section class="static_pages">
        <div class="static_content">
            <h1>Header</h1>

                <p>A little Text</p> 

        </div><!-- END class="static_content" -->
    </section><!-- END class="static_pages" -->
<?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>
```

Any ideas? I've been battling with this for a while now. Thanks!

EDIT: The !doctype and all other header info is in the included header.php file. This is just one of several pages on the site. I have a main index page, which is a long landing page, and this is a static page for stuff like contact, about, etc.

Comment: But the background on the BODY, not your content.

Comment: I just updated the question. I have a main index page that I don't want affected. This is a template for the static pages, like contact, about, etc.

Comment: To do this put a class name on the BODY tag of the other pages, then have CSS declaration to add the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You need to use:

1. A correct `doctype`!

   ```
   <!doctype html>
   ```
2. Background on `body`

   ```
   body {
       background-image: url('../img/cream_dust.png');
       background-repeat: repeat;
   }
   ```
3. Full height body!

   ```
   body {height: 100%;}
   ```

#### Using different background images:

```
<body class="pageOne">
<body class="pageTwo">
<body class="pageThree">
```

#### CSS

```
.pageOne {background-image: url('../img/cream_dust.png');}
.pageTwo {background-image: url('../img/cream_sandwich.png');}
.pageThree {background-image: url('../img/cream_sand.png');}
```

Comment: The !doctype and all other header info is in the included header.php file. This is just one of several pages on the site. I have a main index page, and this is a static page with stuff like contact, about, etc. I'll update the question with this information.

Comment: It works, but how do I specify different backgrounds for different pages if I am applying the background directly to the body?

Comment: Use classes to `body` tag. Updated the answer! Check... :)

Comment: In the absence of `height: 100%`, the `body` is only as tall as the content: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/xfqQe/

Comment: @KevinBoucher Yeah, you need to add height 100%;

Comment: @PraveenKumar Or put the background on the `HTML` tag (see my answer).\

Comment: @KevinBoucher Good idea too! :)

Comment: Great! Thanks guys. Very helpful! This has been driving me crazy!

Comment: @Arel Using `height:100%` is likely to cause issues if the content is longer than the window. You really should add the `background` to your `HTML` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Put the background on your `HTML` tag:

```
html {
    background: transparent url('../img/cream_dust.png') scroll repeat 0 0;
}
```